# When adding a class onclick, is it possible to assess all input values and then readjust the classes based on that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass

Good afternoon, apologies if this more obvious than it appears to myself,

I am having a difficult time adding classes to some input zones, is there a way to add another class to an input and then from this action continue to do more, in one streamlined section of code.

This is a diluted version of the issue I am having as I can't seem to get it to work, I still very am much a novice with JavaScript and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkSubmission(){
        var inputVal = document.getelementbyclassName("compulsory").value;
        if (inputVal == "") {
            $('this').addClass('redborder');
            window.location = "";
        }; 
        else if (inputVal != "" && document.getelementbyclassName('redborder')) {
            $('this').removeClass('redborder');
            window.location.href('');
        };
        else {
            window.location.href('');
        };
    };
    function checkFilled(){
        var inputFill = document.getelementbyclassName('redborder').value;
        if (inputFill != "") {
            document.getelementbyclassName('redborder').style.border-color = "green";
        }; 
    }; 
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .redborder{
        border-color: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="checkSubmission()">Change</button>
    <input class="compulsory">
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much in advanced if you are able to assist.

Comment: `function = checkSubmission()` should give errors, since that's not valid syntax iirc. Remove the `=` sign.

Comment: Okay, have changed that, still not happening. Any other thoughts?

Comment: There are no `document.getelementbyclassName` only `document.getElementsByClassName` that return array like object.

Comment: the classlist api is pretty well supported btw

Comment: Also if you set `window.location = ""` it will refresh the browser so you'll lost new class.

Comment: You're using a rather weird combination of plain JS and JQuery, there's nothing really wrong with that, but generally most people stick to one or the other.

Comment: Conclusion: read the intro chapters again, this code is filled with syntax errors, which the browser console should tell you about.

Comment: semicolons after if before else is syntax error, also you don't need semicolons after function declaration.

Comment: It doesn't appear that your calling checkFilled()

Comment: The syntax for .style.border-color is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a "cleaned up" version I doubt it will work but if you compare it to what you have you can see all the changes mentioned above.

```
function checkSubmission() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementsByClassName("compulsory").value;
    if (inputVal == "") {
        $("this").addClass("redborder");
            window.location = "";
    } else if (inputVal !== "" && document.getElementsByClassName("redborder")) {
        $("this").removeClass("redborder");
            window.location.href("");
    } else {
        window.location.href("");
    }
}

function checkFilled() {
    var inputFill = document.getElementsByClassName("redborder").value;
    if (inputFill !== "") {
        document.getElementsByClassName("redborder").style.border = "thin solid green";
    }
}
```